# QTimer in pyqt loses time?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtimer

I've made a sort of little timer app. It seems to work fine but when I run it in the background the timer (which uses QTimer) doesn't run correctly. It loses time: after 30 minutes elapse, sometimes the timer only goes down 10 minutes.

Watching it, it doesn't seem to run slow. The problem happens when I switch desktops (on my mac) (though it might be slow in some other cases as well). How can I prevent this?

Specifically: There are TimerPanes on the app. They are supposed to count down from a set time (like 3600 seconds). When I run this in the background and switch to watching a video for example however, 10 minutes might elapse ( I checked against my system clock), but the countdown will only have progressed 5 minutes.

Here is the full code, the TimerPane class is the class where QTimer is used. You can run it see if it occurs for you as well:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

Base = declarative_base()

class Task(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'task'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(1000), nullable=False)
    time = Column(Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    color = Column(String(1000), nullable=False, default=0)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///tasks.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

def Convert(t):
    return "{}:{:0>2d}:{:0>2d}".format(t//3600,(t%3600)//60,t%60)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, tasks, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setWindowTitle("Timer")

        layout1 = QHBoxLayout()

        layout1.addWidget(Frame(tasks))

        layout1.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout1.setSpacing(0)

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(layout1)

        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)


        self.setMinimumSize(100,200)

class Frame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, tasks, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Frame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()

        self.create = QPushButton("Create new task")
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.create)
        self.create.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)


        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

        for task in tasks:
            self.vbox.addWidget(TimerPane(task))


    def showDialog(self):
        t=InputDialog()
        if t.exec()==1:
            name, time, color = t.getInputs()
            obj = Task()
            obj.name = name
            obj.time = time
            obj.color= color
            session.add(obj)
            session.commit()
            self.vbox.addWidget(TimerPane(obj))

class TimerPane(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, obj=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TimerPane, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.layout=QVBoxLayout()

        BFont=QFont()
        BFont.setBold(True)

        IFont=QFont()
        IFont.setItalic(True)

        self.namelabel=QLabel()
        self.namelabel.setFont(BFont)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.namelabel)

        self.timelabel=QLabel()
        self.timelabel.setFont(IFont)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.timelabel)

        self.timeleftlabel=QLabel()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.timeleftlabel)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.timeleft=0
        self.time=0
        self.name=''

        if obj:
            self.obj=obj
            self.load()

        self.active=False

        self.deleteButton = QPushButton("Delete")
        self.deleteButton.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed,
            QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.deleteButton)
        self.deleteButton.clicked.connect(self.delete_widget)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.active:
            self.timer_stop()
        else:
            self.timer_start()

    def timer_timeout(self):
        self.timeleft -= 1

        if self.timeleft == 0:
            self.timer_stop()
            self.timeleft = self.obj.time

        self.update_gui()

    def timer_start(self):
        self.my_qtimer = QTimer(self)
        self.my_qtimer.timeout.connect(self.timer_timeout)
        self.my_qtimer.start(1000)
        self.active=True

        self.update_gui()

    def timer_stop(self):
        self.my_qtimer.stop()
        self.active=False

    def update_gui(self,*args):
        self.timeleftlabel.setText(Convert(self.timeleft))

    def load(self):
        p = self.palette()
        p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), QColor(self.obj.color))
        self.setPalette(p)
        self.name=self.obj.name
        self.time=self.obj.time
        self.timeleft=self.obj.time
        try:
            self.namelabel.setText(self.name)
            self.timelabel.setText(Convert(self.time))
            self.timeleftlabel.setText(Convert(self.timeleft))
            self.active=False
        except:
            print("Error, invalid values, delting object")
            self.delete_widget()

    def delete_widget(self):
        session.delete(self.obj)
        session.commit()
        self.deleteLater()

class InputDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.name = QLineEdit(self)
        self.time = QLineEdit(self)
        self.color= QColor(0, 0, 0).name()


        layout = QFormLayout(self)
        layout.addRow("Name", self.name)
        layout.addRow("Time", self.time)

        self.btn = QPushButton('Color', self)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.showColor)

        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel, self);
        layout.addWidget(buttonBox)

        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

    def showColor(self):

        col = QColorDialog.getColor()

        if col.isValid():
            self.color=col.name()

    def getInputs(self):
        return (self.name.text(), self.time.text(), self.color)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    app.setApplicationName("Timer")

    existing_tasks = session.query(Task).all()
    window=MainWindow(existing_tasks)

    window.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, explain yourself better.

Comment: I included the full code, so you can just run it as well. The problem is that the timerpane is supposed to show a timer that counts down but that runs slow for some reason.

Comment: I appreciate that you provide an MRE but that is not enough since providing code without explanation does not make you understand the objective of code so I have asked for more details. Why do you point out that the timer is slow? What do you compare it with? How can I verify it?

Comment: Well there are Timer Panes on the app. They are supposed to count down from a set time (like 3600 seconds). When I run this in the background and switch to watching a video for example however, 10 minutes might elapse ( I checked against my system clock), but the countdown will only have progressed 5 minutes. I think it somehow stops running for some reason maybe?

Comment: 1) Okay, this explanation is very clear so you should edit your question and add it there. 2) From what I understand is that to set it a name, the number of seconds and a color are set, then when you press the TimerPane the counter starts then you open another program (for example a video player) and after a while you check the elapsed time but does not match the time elapsed by a timer on your OS. I am right?

Comment: 3) In addition to what you say, I can find a bug: for example, suppose you set your timer in 10 seconds so you press the TimerPane every 0.1 seconds, before that you will see that the time shown will never pass since the counter never decreases. What behavior should be correct?

Comment: 2) Yes exactly. 3)Ive noticed that as well but am not too worried about that behavior because I intend to use the timer for long stretches like 20 minutes-hours. If it has no side effects I'm okay with the TimerPane doing that especially as I don't see a method that works better and is still comparably simple.

Comment: Hm I guess using the system clock would be better than using a qtimer, as it would prevent that bug and work even if my laptop went to sleep. Still don't know why my app stops running when its in the background though or how to keep it running.